# Delete Multiple Rows at once If Cell = 0 Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This code works fine deleteing 1 row at a time if criteria met. How can I get it to delete say 10 or 20 rows at once if criteria is met ?

It just very slow when I need about 50-100 rows deleted if criteria is met.

```
function DeleteYESColumnF() {
// This Code will delete any "YES" in Column F.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
var values = rows.getValues();

var rowsDeleted = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var row = values[i];
if (row[5] == 'YES') {
sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
rowsDeleted++;
}
}
};
```

I am aware apps script can do this. I am looking for someone who knows what to add to this script to do what I have asked.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am aware apps script can do this. I am looking for someone who knows what to add to this script to do what I have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Deleting rows in groups when they are consecutive**

```
function runOne() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  
  var A=[];//The array of rows to delete
  var d=0;
  var A=values.map(function(r,i){if(r[0]==true)return i+1;}).filter(function(e){return(e);});
  for(var i=0;i<A.length;) {
    var n=0;
    var idx=i;
    while((idx+1+n)<A.length && A[idx+1+n]-A[idx+n]==1){n++;}
    sheet.deleteRows(A[i]-d,n+1);
    d+=n+1;
    i+=n+1;
  }
}
```

Here's what my sheet looks like before deleting starts.  I have checkboxes in column one to serve as the reason for deleting a row but you could use any conditional

[image]

Sheet after deleting ends:

[image]

I played around with this a bit and I found this to be a little faster.

```
//A is an Array of row numbers to delete
function dRows(A) {
  var d=0;
  var oA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<A.length;) {
    var n=0;
    while((i+1+n)<A.length && A[i+1+n]-A[i+n]==1){n++;}
    oA.push({row:A[i]-d,num:++n});
    d+=n;
    i+=n;
  }
  return oA;//deleteRows parameters array
}

function runTwo() {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  
  var A=values.map(function(r,i){if(r[0]==true)return i+1;}).filter(function(e){return(e);});
  dRows(A).forEach(function(r){sheet.deleteRows(r.row,r.num)});
}
```